# Sum of $k$-combination with repetitions

Tags: combinatorics

I can see that there are $\binom{n+k-1}{k}$ cases of choosing k items of n types with repetition from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset_coefficient#Counting_multisets.

I wonder whether there is any formula about its sum for varying $k$.
In particular, I am interested in $\sum_{k=1}^{N} \binom{n+k-1}{k}$.

Does anyone have an idea, or a link about this or anything similar to this one?

Update: I changed $nk$ to $N$. Actually $N = np$ for some positive integer $p$, but I think this is not necessary.

---

*Remark*

This question was closed for being a duplicate of [How to simplify $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{n + i - 1}{i}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220967/how-to-simplify-sum-i-1k-binomn-i-1i). However, the latter was posted in Apr 5, 2015, hence after this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Hockeystick Identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity#Hockey-Stick_Identity) states that for positive integers $n>r$, we have $\displaystyle\sum^n_{i=r}{i\choose r}={n+1\choose r+1}$.

See that link for several proofs.

Thus, $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{N}\dbinom{n+k-1}{k} = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 0}^{N}\dbinom{n+k-1}{n-1} \overset{i = n+k-1}{=}\displaystyle\sum_{i = n-1}^{n+N-1}\dbinom{i}{n-1} = \dbinom{n+N}{n}$.

Subtract $\dbinom{n+k-1}{0} = 1$ from both sides to get $\displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{N}\dbinom{n+k-1}{k} = \dbinom{n+N}{n}-1$.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{k = 1}^{N}{n + k - 1 \choose k}:\ {\large ?}}$

> The binomial $\ds{{n + k - 1 \choose k}}$ is non-zero whenever
>   $\ds{0\ \leq\ k\ \leq\ n + k - 1\ \imp\ k \geq 0\,,\ n \geq 1}$. Hereafter, we'll assume those conditions are satisfied.

\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\sum_{k = 1}^{N}{n + k - 1 \choose k}}
=\sum_{k = 1}^{N}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + k - 1} \over z^{k + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[2mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z}\sum_{k = 1}^{N}
\pars{1 + z \over z}^{k}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n - 1} \over z}
{1 + z \over z}{\bracks{\pars{1 + z}/z}^{N} - 1 \over \pars{1 + z}/z - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}
\bracks{{\pars{1 + z}^{N} \over z^{N}} - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
\\[3mm]&=\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + N} \over z^{N + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
-\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n} \over z}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
=\color{#66f}{\large{N + n \choose N} - 1}
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain the very first equality--${n + k - 1 \choose k} = \oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{n + k - 1} \over z^{k + 1}}
\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}$, or do you have a reference?

Comment: @user15765 The pole of $\displaystyle{\large\left(1 + z\right)^{n + k - 1} \over z^{k + 1}}$ is found by expanding the binomial in the numerator. The power $\displaystyle{\large z^{k}}$ has the coefficient $\displaystyle{\large{n + k - 1 \choose k}}$. Indeed, That's is an identity. Quite useful.

Comment: @user15765 If you expand the binomial in the numerator the only contribution ( Residue Theorem ) arises from the power $\large z^{k}$.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much for the derivation.

Comment: @user15765 I'm glad it was useful for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can be written as a telescopic sum (with $a = n-1$)

$$\sum_{k=1}^{N} \binom{a+k}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} \left(\binom{a+k+1}{k} - \binom{a+k}{k-1}\right)$$

which gives us the answer to be

$$ \binom{a+N+1}{N} - \binom{a+N}{0} = \binom{n+N}{N} - 1$$