# How to simplify $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{n + i - 1}{i}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to simplify $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{n + i - 1}{i}$? I tried reducing the sum to $\binom{n}{1}, \binom{n}{2}, \binom{n}{3}$ and so on but couldn't get a pattern.

Comment: Hint: Pascal's Rule.

Comment: Observe that  $$\sum_{i=1}^2\binom{n+i-1}i=\binom n1+\binom{n+1}2=\frac{2n+(n+1)n}2=\frac{n^2+3n}2=\binom{n+2}2-1$$

Comment: See [$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom{i+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k}{k}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833451/prove-sum-i-0n-binomik-1k-1-binomnkk)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem becomes trivial on using [Pascal's Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule). Using it, we have,

$$\binom{n+i-1}{i}=\binom{n+i}{i}-\binom{n+i-1}{i-1}$$

Now, substituting this into our required sum (say $S$) gives us a telescoping sum (the middle terms gets cancelled out).

$$S=\sum_{i=1}^k \binom{n+i-1}{i}=\sum_{i=1}^k \left\{\binom{n+i}{i}-\binom{n+i-1}{i-1}\right\}\\ \implies S=\binom{n+1}{1}-\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+2}{2}-\binom{n+1}{1}+\ldots +\binom{n+k}{k}-\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\\ \implies S=\binom{n+k}{k}-\binom{n}{0}\\ \implies \boxed{S=\dbinom{n+k}{k}-1}$$