# Combinatorics : number of non-decreasing series of r distinct numbers where the size of series ranges from 1 to N

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations

I understand that number of non decreasing sequences of size M with N distinct numbers is (N+M−1)C(M). However, I'm interested in finding out the number of such series of r distinct integers where the size ranges from 1 to N. So its summation of (N+M−1)C(M) where N=1 to N. Is there a way I can directly get the answer without summing. A formula or a pattern that may apply ?

-Aman

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to simplify $\sum_{i=1}^{k}\binom{n + i - 1}{i}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220967/how-to-simplify-sum-i-1k-binomn-i-1i)

Comment: Your question isn’t entirely clear. Suppose that $r=2$, you have the two numbers $1$ and $2$, and $N=3$; are $1$, $2$, $11$, $12$, $22$, $111$, $112$, $122$, and $222$ the sequences that you want to count?

Comment: If so, then @Prasun is correct, and you should look at that link.