# Simplify the expression $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+2}{2}+\cdots +\binom{n+k}{k}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Simplify the expression $\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+2}{2}+\cdots +\binom{n+k}{k}$

My attempt: Using the formula $\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$

$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+2}{2}+\cdots \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}+\binom{n+k}{k}$

=$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+2}{2}+\cdots +\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}+(\binom{n+k-1}{k}+\binom{n+k-1}{k-1})$

=$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n+1}{1}+\binom{n+2}{2}+\cdots +2\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}+\binom{n+k-1}{k}$

I can again use the same formula for the term $2\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$, and in the next to step to the term $3\binom{n+k-2}{k-2}$.

But I don't think this way the expression will get simplified.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint, pick for $n$ a value, say$5$ and work it our numerically. What do you get?

Comment: Start from the other end.
$$\binom n0+\binom{n+1}1=\binom{n+1}0+\binom{n+1}1=\binom{n+2}1$$ et cetera. And, this has surely been covered on our site earlier. IIRC some folks (most likely Canadian) call it *the hockey stick identity*.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I call it the hockey stick identity and I'm from the deep south.  That may be a fault of the books/teachers I've had in the past though.  Regardless, it appears [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1490794/proof-of-the-hockey-stick-identity-sum-t-0n-binom-tk-binomn1k1).

Comment: LOL @JMoravitz! Well the NHL has spread further South (Tampa Bay, Nashville,...) Thanks for the find.

Comment: @JMoravitz The link you posted is a different question, the k is fixed over there. Is not it? As  in my question the $k$ is also varying.

Comment: A fair point, Babai. The symmetry $\binom n k=\binom n {n-k}$ transforms one to the other.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's true. Thank you.

Comment: Babai, [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1220973/11619) may be more applicable here.

Comment: It really is the same question. Just apply $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n}{n-r}$. The hockey-stick visualization makes it clear it's a duplicate.

Comment: Also have a look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1658490/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First show that $\large{n\choose r}={{n-1}\choose {r-1}}+{{n-1}\choose r}$,

from which we get $\large{{n+r+1}\choose r}={{n+r}\choose r}+{{n+r}\choose {r-1}}$

By the same rule, $\large{{n+r}\choose {r-1}}={{n+r-1}\choose {r-1}}+{{n+r-1}\choose {r-2}}$

$\large{{n+r-1}\choose {r-2}}={{n+r-2}\choose {r-2}}+{{n+r-3}\choose {r-3}}$

$..$  $\quad \quad \quad \quad ..$ $ \quad \quad \quad ..$

$..$  $\quad \quad \quad \quad ..$ $ \quad \quad \quad ..$

$..$  $\quad \quad \quad \quad ..$ $ \quad \quad \quad ..$

$\large{{n+3}\choose {2}}={{n+2}\choose {2}}+{{n+2}\choose {1}}$

$\large{{n+2}\choose {1}}={{n+1}\choose {1}}+{{n+1}\choose {0}}$

Adding, we get $\large{n\choose 0}+{{n+1}\choose 1}+...+{{n+r-1}\choose {r-1}}+{{n+r}\choose r}={{n+r+1}\choose r}$

---

Alternatively, we can fix any $r$ of the $(n+r+1)$ objects given. Label them $A_1,A_2,...A_r$. Now our choices of $r$ objects from the $(n+r+1)$ objects may or may not contain any or all of the set $\{A_1,A_2,...,A_r\}$.

**Case I:** It does not contain $A_1$

This will happen in $\large{{n+r}\choose r}$ ways as the $r$ things have to be chosen from the remaining $(n+r)$ things.

**Case II:** It contains $A_1$ but does not contain $A_2$.

This will happen in $\large{{n+r-1}\choose {r-1}}$ ways, because having chosen $A_1$ and rejectd $A_2$, we have only $(n+r-1)$ things to choose from and we need only $(r-1)$.

$...$

**Case r:** It contains $A_1,A_2,...,A_{r-1}$ but does not contain $A_r$.

This will happen in $\large {{n+1}\choose 1}$ ways.

**Case $(r+1)$:** It contains $A_1,A_2,...,A_r$.

This will happen in $\large{n\choose 0}=1$ way.

Hence, $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{r}{{n+k}\choose k}={{n+r+1}\choose r}$