# Simplifying $\sum_{k=0}^b{n+k \choose n+k-a}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let $a,b,n$ positive integers such that $a \leq n$. Can we simplify this formula?

$\sum_{k=0}^b{n+k \choose n+k-a}={ n \choose n-a } + { n+1 \choose n+1-a } + \dots + {n+b \choose n+b-a}$

I was stuck at the beginning except for the thought to use the hockey-stick identity somehow like mentioned in the comments.

Comment: We can simplify it but first let us see where you are stuck

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/870219/sum-of-k-combination-with-repetitions

Comment: You could also have a look at  [Proof of the Hockey-Stick Identity: $\sum\limits_{t=0}^n \binom tk = \binom{n+1}{k+1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1490794) and [other questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1490794).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$S=\sum_{k=0}^{b} {n+k \choose n+k-a}=\sum_{k=0}^{b} {n+k \choose a}=[x^a]\sum_{k=0}^{b} (1+x)^{n+k}$$
$$S=[x^a] (1+x)^n \frac{(1+x)^{b+1}-1}{1+x-1}=[x^{a+1}]~((1+x)^{n+b+1}-(1+x)^n).$$
$$S={n+b+1 \choose a+1}-{n \choose 1+a}.$$
Here $[x^k]g(x)$ means the coefficient of $x^k$ in $g(x).$

Comment: shouldn't it be $ x^{a-1}$? why did it become a+1? ( Line-2)

Comment: It is because of $x=1+x-1$ down. Check that $[x^k](g(x)/x)=[x^{k+1}]g(x)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :** Make  use of the simple Pascal's identity, i.e. : $~\dbinom{n}{k} + \dbinom{n}{k+1} = \dbinom{n+1}{k+1}$

---

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^b \dbinom{n+k}{n+k-a}  &= \sum_{k=0}^b \dbinom{n+k}{a}\\
&= \dbinom{n}{a+1} + \dbinom{n}{a} + \dbinom{n+1}{a} + \cdots + \dbinom{n+b}{a} - \dbinom{n}{a+1}\\
&= \dbinom{n+1}{a+1} + \dbinom{n+1}{a} + \dbinom{n+2}{a} + \cdots + \dbinom{n+b}{a} - \dbinom{n}{a+1}\\
&\hspace{1.4cm}\vdots\hspace{2.2cm}\vdots\\
&= \dbinom{n+b}{a+1} + \dbinom{n+b}{a} - \dbinom{n}{a+1}\\
&= \dbinom{n+b+1}{a+1} - \dbinom{n}{a+1}
\end{align*}

Hope it helps.